# Session not getting maintained

Tags: java, session, web-applications, load-balancing

I have deployed a java web application in 2 servers. Using Load balancer, i am accessing the application. Sometimes, the session is not getting maintained because of the requests being sent to different servers. The single session is not getting maintained in the appropriate server.

Kindly provide your suggestions on how to overcome this issue.

Comment: Use session clustering, either built-in or (usually easier) with Spring Session.

Comment: There are many ways to solve this, such as sticky sessions in the load balancer (easiest, but doesn't scale as well, and makes the application less reliable from the users perspective, and makes rollouts of new versions harder), or letting your app server handle synchronization of the session (one-size fits all, hard to optimize, depends on Java serialization) or you do it yourself in the app, or with the help of some libraries, possibly using clustered in-memory caches or more simply a shared database.